# Can someone tell me why my White Noise, Pink Noise and Brown Noise won't work (Web Audio API)

Tags: audio, cross-browser, web-audio-api

```
<head> 
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/loopy_styles.css" />
    <script>
        context = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
        var soundBuffers = [null,null,null,null,null,null,null];
        window.onload = function() {
          loadSound('sounds/fire_test1.wav', 1);
          loadSound('sounds/wind_test.wav', 2);
          loadSound('sounds/rain_test.wav', 3);
          loadSound('sounds/stream.mp3', 4);
          loadSound('sounds/spring_test.wav', 5);
          loadSound('sounds/thunder.mp3', 6);
        };

        var currentlyPlayingSoundNum = 0;
        var currentlyPlayingSound = null;
        function play_sound(num){
          if (num) {
            document.getElementById('playBtn'+num+'_play').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('playBtn'+num+'_stop').style.display = 'block';
            currentlyPlayingSoundNum = num;
            currentlyPlayingSound = context.createBufferSource();
            currentlyPlayingSound.looping = true;
            currentlyPlayingSound.buffer = soundBuffers[num];
            currentlyPlayingSound.connect(context.destination);
            currentlyPlayingSound.start(0);
          }
        }
        function stop_sound(num){
          if(num){
            document.getElementById('playBtn'+num+'_play').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('playBtn'+num+'_stop').style.display = 'none';
          }
          if (currentlyPlayingSound) {document.getElementById('playBtn'+currentlyPlayingSoundNum+'_play').style.display = 'block';
            document.getElementById('playBtn'+currentlyPlayingSoundNum+'_stop').style.display = 'none';
            currentlyPlayingSound.stop(0);
            currentlyPlayingSound = null;
            currentlyPlayingSoundNumber = 0;
          }
        }
        function loadSound(url, bufferNum) {
          var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
          request.open('GET', url, true);
          request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

          request.onload = function() {
            var successCallback = function(buffer) {
              soundBuffers[bufferNum] = buffer;
            }
            var errorCallback = function(e) {
              console.log(e);
            }
            context.decodeAudioData(request.response, successCallback, errorCallback);
          }
          request.send();
        }
    </script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
      var whiteNoise = context.createWhiteNoise();
      var whiteGain = context.createGainNode();
      whiteGain.gain.value = 70;
      whiteNoise.connect(whiteGain);
      whiteGain.connect(audioContext.destination);

      var pinkNoise = context.createPinkNoise();
      var pinkGain = context.createGainNode();
      pinkGain.gain.value = 70;
      pinkNoise.connect(pinkGain);
      pinkGain.connect(audioContext.destination);

      var brownNoise = context.createBrownNoise();
      var brownGain = context.createGainNode();
      brownGain.gain.value = 70;
      brownNoise.connect(brownGain);
      brownGain.connect(context.destination);

      var toggleDemo = function(colour, gain) {

          var handler = function(e) {
              if (gain.gain.value == 0.0) {
                  document.getElementById('playBtn'+colour+'_play').style.display = 'none';
                  document.getElementById('playBtn'+colour+'_stop').style.display = 'block';
                  gain.gain.value = 0.7;
              } else {
                  document.getElementById('playBtn'+colour+'_play').style.display = 'block';
                  document.getElementById('playBtn'+colour+'_stop').style.display = 'none';
                  gain.gain.value = 0.0;
              }
          };
          return handler;
      };
    </script>
    <script>
        (function(AudioContext) {
      AudioContext.prototype.createWhiteNoise = function(bufferSize) {
        bufferSize = bufferSize || 4096;
        var node = this.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
        node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
          var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
          for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
            output[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
          }
        }
        return node;
      };

      AudioContext.prototype.createPinkNoise = function(bufferSize) {
        bufferSize = bufferSize || 4096;
        var b0, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6;
        b0 = b1 = b2 = b3 = b4 = b5 = b6 = 0.0;
        var node = this.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
        node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
          var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
          for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
            var white = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            b0 = 0.99886 * b0 + white * 0.0555179;
            b1 = 0.99332 * b1 + white * 0.0750759;
            b2 = 0.96900 * b2 + white * 0.1538520;
            b3 = 0.86650 * b3 + white * 0.3104856;
            b4 = 0.55000 * b4 + white * 0.5329522;
            b5 = -0.7616 * b5 - white * 0.0168980;
            output[i] = b0 + b1 + b2 + b3 + b4 + b5 + b6 + white * 0.5362;
            output[i] *= 0.11; // (roughly) compensate for gain
            b6 = white * 0.115926;
          }
        }
        return node;
      };

      AudioContext.prototype.createBrownNoise = function(bufferSize) {
        bufferSize = bufferSize || 4096;
        var lastOut = 0.0;
        var node = this.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 1, 1);
        node.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
          var output = e.outputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
          for (var i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++) {
            var white = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
            output[i] = (lastOut + (0.02 * white)) / 1.02;
            lastOut = output[i];
            output[i] *= 3.5; // (roughly) compensate for gain
          }
        }
        return node;
      };
    })(window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <title>Ambient Sound Generator</title>  
  </head>
<body>

<div class="background">
  <div id="intro-text">
    <!--This code give us our sharing buttons-->
      <div id="share-buttons">
      <span class='st_facebook_large' displayText='Facebook'></span>
      <span class='st_twitter_large' displayText='Tweet'></span>
      <span class='st_tumblr_large' displayText='Tumblr'></span>
      <span class='st_stumbleupon_large' displayText='StumbleUpon'></span>
      <span class='st_linkedin_large' displayText='LinkedIn'></span>
    </div>
    <h1 id="site-title">Ambient Sound Generator</h1>
    <p>Mix ambient sounds together to block out distractions and help you focus or relax</p>
    <p>Click the buttons below to begin</p>
  </div>

  <div id="button-container">

    <div id="vol_main">
    <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="70" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">
      <p>Volume</p>
    </div>

    <div id="btn1">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/fire-pause.png" name="Fire" id="playBtn1_play" onclick="play_sound(1);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/fire-play.png" name="Fire" id="playBtn1_stop" onclick="stop_sound(1);" style="display:none"/>
    </div>
    <div id="btn2">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/wind-pause.png" name="Wind" id="playBtn2_play" onclick="play_sound(2);"  />
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/wind-play.png" name="Wind" id="playBtn2_stop" onclick="stop_sound(2);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="btn3">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/rain-pause.png" name="Rain" id="playBtn3_play" onclick="play_sound(3);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/rain-play.png" name="Rain" id="playBtn3_stop" onclick="stop_sound(3);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="btn4">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/stream-pause.png" name="Stream" id="playBtn4_play" onclick="play_sound(4);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/stream-play.png" name="Stream" id="playBtn4_stop" onclick="stop_sound(4);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="btn6">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/thunder-pause.png" name="Thunder" id="playBtn6_play" onclick="play_sound(6);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/thunder-play.png" name="Thunder" id="playBtn6_stop" onclick="stop_sound(6);" style="display:none"/>    <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
    <div id="btn5">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/forest-pause.png" name="Spring" id="playBtn5_play" onclick="play_sound(5);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/forest-play.png" name="Spring" id="playBtn5_stop" onclick="stop_sound(5);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
     <div id="btn7">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/whitenoise-pause.png" name="White" id="playBtnWhite_play" onclick="toggleDemo(white, whiteGain)"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/whitenoise-play.png" name="White" id="playBtnWhite_stop" onclick="toggleDemo(white, whiteGain);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
     <div id="btn8">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/pinknoise-pause.png" name="Pink" id="playBtnPink_play" onclick="toggleDemo(pink, pinkGain);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/pinknoise-play.png" name="Pink" id="playBtn8Pink_stop" onclick="toggleDemo(pink, pinkGain);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
     <div id="btn9">
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/brownnoise-pause.png" name="Brown" id="playBtnBrown_play" onclick="toggleDemo(brown, brownGain);"/>
      <input type="image" class="pp_img" src="img/brownnoise-play.png" name="Brown" id="playBtnBrown_stop" onclick="toggleDemo(brown, brownGain);" style="display:none"/>
      <!--<p><input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" onchange="sample.changeVolume();">Volume</p>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
<!--Code for changing background colour, using the time settings-->
    <script>
      function refreshData(){
        x = 1;
        var d = new Date()
        var h = d.getHours();
        var m = d.getMinutes();
        var s = d.getSeconds();

        if (h<=9) {h = '0'+h};
        if (m<=9) {m = '0'+m};
        if (s<=9) {s = '0'+s};

        var color = '#'+h+m+s;
          $("div.background").css("background-color", color);
          $("p#hex").text(color);
          setTimeout(refreshData, x*100);
      }
      refreshData();
  </script>
```

I've a few queries, if anyone can help:

1. Can someone tell me why my White Noise, Pink Noise and Brown Noise aren't working and how I can possibly fix it.
2. If you can see why this wouldn't work in Chrome that'd be helpful as it currently only works in Safari.
3. How can I connect my volume control to a gainNode for controlling to overall volume of the application.

Answer (score 1):

1 & 2) createGainNode -> createGain.

Comment: Ok so I have updated the code to try add the volume sliders, here is an example for one sound, can someone explain why it will not play?
    <code>sound1.gainNode = context.createGain();
    sound1.source = context.createBufferSource();
    sound1.source.buffer = soundBuffers[num];
    sound1.source.connect(sound1.gainNode);
    sound1.gainNode.connect(context.destination)
    sound1.source.looping = true;
    sound1.source.start(0);</code>

Comment: Hmm.  Are you sure your buffer has finished loading when you call sound1.source.buffer = soundBuffers[num]?

Comment: soundBuffers[] is loaded at page load, so I think so. I think the issue I have is that it won't loop the files in Chrome or Firefox but will in Safari.

Comment: Ah, it's playing but not looping.  Got it.  (Note that the soundBuffers[] load may be STARTED at page load, but maybe the buffers haven't been created yet?